# A basic confusion of diagonalizable matrix related to linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$$M=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 3 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 3\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
This matrix has eigenvalues $5,2,2$. Eigenspace corresponds to $5$ is $(c (1 1 1) ) $ and corresponds to $2$ is $(a (1   0 -1)+b (0   1 -1)$.Clearly $M$is diagonalizable and hence it is similar to $D$.
Where

$$D=\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

So I expect that $D (1 1 1)=5 (1 1 1)$, but I don't know why this does not happen here, $D$ is obtained from the same linear transformation corresponds to the basis obtained by eigenvectors..

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

The diagonalisable matrices have the standard basis elements as eigenvectors. So
$$D\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}=5\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}.$$
Also $\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$. One of the aims
of diagonalisation is to replace the old eigenvectors by a really simple
system of eigenvectors.

Comment: But both of them comes from same linear transformation,corresponds to 5 ,c(1 1 1) is an eigenvector.But from D ,(1 0 0 ) is a

Comment: But M and D comes from same linear transformation.c (1 1 1) is the eigenspace corresponds to 5.From D we see (d(1 0 0)) is the eigenspace corresponds to 5.But both the matrix represents same linear transformation,why are they different?

Comment: @SubhajitSaha because they are matrices w.r.t. a different basis. A linear function has a different matrix for every pair of bases in domain and codomain.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I know it but I am saying that both the matrices comes from same linear transformation but why the matrices does not transform a vector to same vector?

Comment: The vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ in the standard basis denotes the same vector as $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ in the eigenvector basis $\mathcal{B}$ (see my answer). A vector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ in basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ by definition means $x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 + x_3v_3$, so the exact numbers in a vector notation are meaningless without a fixed basis.

Answer (score 1):

$$D\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}  =5 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ as expected. The vector (1,1,1) in standard coordinates is just $(1,0,0)$ in the basis of eigenvectors 
$$ \mathcal{B} = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

And $D$ is the matrix in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ of the linear map $T$ which is given in the standard basis by $M$; a vector like $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ has no meaning without specifying what basis we are using.